# Add information to DB only after admin approval - Django

Tags: django

I built a site that users can add word and association how to remember the word to a database.
However I don't want that the DATA will save automatic
I want to add options that only after the approval of admin the word will add to the DB and other users will see it.

how can do I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were building such system I would create specialized "status" field on my model which would store have several states, for example:

- `ACCEPTED` - means word is accepted by admin
- `REVIEW` - means word needs to be reviewed by admin and accepted.

When you create a word it is saved with status `ACCEPTED` and will be displayed in some queue for admin for review, but regular users will not see this word (you can filter queryset so it only return objects with status="ACCEPTED").

Comment: `approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)`  I add this to my models now how I add the option to edit the bolleanfueld to True from the admin ?

Comment: Do you have your model registered in admin? If so it should automatically appear unless you explicitly specify which fields to display in Admin form.